# How to change the labels of the Document Type drop-down for AP Payment

Tags: acumatica

I am attempting to change the labels of the Document Type drop-down on the AP Payment form, similar to what I did with AP Invoice in this previous question: [How to change the appearance of APInvoice types (Bill, Credit Adjustment, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694504/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-apinvoice-types-bill-credit-adjustment-etc). I am attempting to change the labels of Debit and Credit Adjustment to become Credit and Debit Memos for a client that is more familiar with that terminology. When attempting I get an error referencing to an unequal lengths of the arrays I use.

I am also attempting to change the labels of the Adjd Document Type drop-down for the line item of AP Payment to do the same thing. However, the code I have compiled does not cause any of the drop-down labels to change.

I have attempted to use similar code used to change the labels of the AP Invoice Document Type, however I have eliminated references to migration mode due to it not appearing in the attribute for the drop-down in AP Payment.

CustomAPPaymentType:

```
    public class CustomAPPaymentType : APPaymentType
    {
        public new static readonly string[] NewLabels = new string[]
        {
          "Check",
          "Credit Memo",
          "Prepayment",
          "Vendor Refund",
          "Voided Refund",
          "Voided Check"
        };

        public new class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
        {
            public ListAttribute() : base(APPaymentType.Values, 
                                               CustomAPPaymentType.NewLabels )
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

CustomAPPaymentTypeListAttribute:

```
    public class CustomAPPaymentTypeListAttribute : 
                                            CustomAPPaymentType.ListAttribute
    {

           public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
           {
                this._AllowedValues = new string[]
                {
                      "CHK",
                      "ADR",
                      "PPM",
                      "REF",
                      "VRF",
                      "VCK"
                };
                this._AllowedLabels = new string[]
                {
                      "Check",
                      "Credit Memo",
                      "Prepayment",
                      "Vendor Refund",
                      "Voided Refund",
                      "Voided Check"
                };
                this._NeutralAllowedLabels = new string[]
                {
                      "Check",
                      "Credit Memo",
                      "Prepayment",
                      "Vendor Refund",
                      "Voided Refund",
                      "Voided Check"
                };
                base.CacheAttached(sender);
           }
     }
```

APPaymentEntry:

```
     public class APPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntry>
     {

            #region Event Handlers
            [PXDBString(3, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true)]
            [PXDefault]
            [CustomAPPaymentTypeList]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type", Visibility = 
                PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Enabled = true, TabOrder = 0)]
            [PXFieldDescription]

        protected virtual void APPayment_DocType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
        }

            [PXDBString(3, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, InputMask = "")]
            [PXDefault(APDocType.Invoice)]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Type", 
                        Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
            [CustomAPInvoiceType.AdjdList()]
    protected virtual void APAdjust_AdjdDocType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
    }

           #endregion
  }
```

CustomAPInvoiceType: Includes the AdjdListAttribute in order to alter the Adjd Document Type drop-down

```
    public class CustomAPInvoiceType : APInvoiceType
    {

        public new static readonly string[] NewLabels = new string[]
        {
            "Bill",
            "Debit Memo",
            "Credit Memo",
            "Prepayment"
        };

        public new class ListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
        {
            public ListAttribute() : base(APInvoiceType.Values, 
                                                CustomAPInvoiceType.NewLabels)
            {
            }
        }

        public new class AdjdListAttribute : PXStringListAttribute
        {
            public AdjdListAttribute() : base(APInvoiceType.Values, 
                                                CustomAPInvoiceType.NewLabels)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like is for the AP Payment form's drop-downs for the Document Type and the Adjd Document Type to reflect the changes I am attempting, changing the Debit and Credit Adjustment labels to be Credit and Debit Memo. The error I receive when I attempt to access the AP Payment form is:

Error #0: The length of the values array is not equal to the length of labels array. Parameter name: allowedLabels.

I'm unsure on how to proceed, it seems like I either have too many 'Labels' or 'Values' but it isn't clear on which. I tried to be as accurate to the current setup for current types for APPayment, any advice on where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)**
To change the labels of Document Type field: 
"Debit/Credit Adjustment" to "Debit/Credit Memos" 
you do not need to write any line of code.

You can achieve this by using "Translation Dictionaries" screen (SM200540)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdHnBtRPOd0

We customize an attribute in development when we need to add or remove "Document Type" from the string list.

**2)**
Another reason to use the Translation is that you will be able to change it in multiple places of the application (like messages), places that you did not think yet :) like this one: "Only Invoices and Debit Adjustments can be selected for payment."

You will do it faster than development solution :)
Also you can publish the changes into a Customization Project (System Locales).

**3)**
Good practice: for Labels, use constants inside PXLocalizable class not literal strings. In this way it will be multi-language or the customer may be able to "edit" any labels that may need.

Comment: Thank you so much this was a much easier solution than I expected, I'm much more used to solving problems with coding. I wasn't familiar with the Translation Dictionary, very useful tool!